# Forcing Django ORM filter field ordering for composite index

Tags: django, django-nonrel

I have a composite index I setup which requires the fields to be requested in a specific order. For example, field1, field2, field3

How can I force the Django ORM to make the query with the order I've specified? For example of Django instead decides to request 'field2, field1, field3', then my DB Index will not work and it will be a slow query.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing now and the query it's generating? Have you tried doing .order_by('field1', 'field2', 'field3')?

Comment: Sadly django-nonrel doesnt support the .query property to view the query.. Also, your suggestion isn't quite correct. For instance, Car.objects.filter(make="Honda", model="Accord"), I would expect the query to be cars.find({make: "Honda", model: "Accord"}) in that order. The reason it needs to be in this order is because i have an index {"make": 1, "model": 1}